# Why do we need surjectivity in this theorem?

Tags: general-topology

In class we proved the following theorem:

Given $X_1,X_2$ ordered sets. Then any surjective increasing $\phi: X_1 \to X_2$ is continuous wrt the interval topology on $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I was asked to find an example to prove that the surjectivity condition above is essential: What does this mean? Do I need to find an increasing $f$  which is not surjective but continuous? How can I construct one?

Comment: By an ordered set, do you mean a totally ordered set, or a partially ordered set?

Comment: totally ordered sets

Comment: @WillieRosario You have to find a non surjective map which is not continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is asking you to find a strictly increasing map $\phi : X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ that isn't continuous, and to prove that $\phi$ isn't continuous. The phrasing of the question offers an important hint, namely that you should be thinking about non-surjective choices of $\phi$, since no surjective choice is going to work.

Here's a pretty substantial hint. Take $X_1$ equal to $\mathbb{N}$ with an element $a_0$ adjoined "at the end", and $X_2$ equal to $\mathbb{N}$ with two elements $b_0$ and $b_1$ adjoined "at the end," such that $b_0 \leq b_1$. Let $\phi : X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ be the map that takes $a_0$ to $b_1$, while leaving all the natural numbers unchanged. Now prove that $\phi$ isn't continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I now see that I misunderstood what you mean by increasing; you mean what I would call "strictly increasing." I'll leave this answer here anyway, since it shows that we cannot weaken this condition in the theorem.

**Original answer.** This isn't true even if we assume surjectivity. Let $P = \{-1,1\}$ denote the ordered set such that $-1 \leq 1$. Then every subset of $P$ is open with respect to the interval topology. Now define $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow P$ by asserting that $f(x) = 1$ iff $x$ is positive. Then despite that $\{-1\} \subseteq P$ is open, nonetheless $f^{-1}(\{-1\})$ is not.